# Algorithm, which can remove outliers, but do not blur other part of image

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, filtering

Is there any algorithm, which can remove outliers, but do not blur other part of image?

Only for example, when we use [`cv::StereoBM/SBGM`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#StereoBM) or [`cv::gpu::StereoConstantSpaceBP`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#gpu::StereoConstantSpaceBP) from opencv, then we can have outliers, as shown in relevant question: [opencv sgbm produces outliers on object edges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30784030/1558037) Also, we can get large bursts of intensity (strong variations) in local area of image with similar colors: [image]

And many other cases...

The simplest solution is using `cv::medianBlur()`, but it will smooth all image, not only outliers: [Median filter example video](http://www.bogotobogo.com/OpenCV/images/blur/m.mp4)

Is there any algorithm which smoothes only outliers, and It does not affect the rest of the image?

Is there anything better than this?

```
// get cv::Mat src_frame ...
int outliers_size = 10;
int outliers_intensive = 100;
int ksize = outliers_size*2 + 1; // smooth all outliers smaller than 11x11
cv::Mat smoothed;
cv::medianBlur( src_frame, smoothed, ksize  );
cv::Mat diff;
cv::absdiff( src_frame, smoothed, diff );
cv::Mat mask = diff > Scalar( outliers_intensive );

smoothed.copyTo( src_frame, mask );
// we have smoothed only small outliers areas in src_frame
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the bilateral filter?

OpenCV says:

> we have explained some filters which main goal is to smooth an input
>   image. However, sometimes the filters do not only dissolve the noise,
>   but also smooth away the edges. To avoid this (at certain extent at
>   least), we can use a bilateral filter.

[image: Here's what it looks like on a depth image]

OpenCV has this built-in: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=bilateralfilter#bilateralfilter

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I looked for the bilateral filter and especially for the `cv::gpu::DisparityBilateralFilter`: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#gpu::DisparityBilateralFilter   But as you shown on your picture - bilateral filter: 1. don't removes outliers - result image has still the same outliers, 2. it smoothes all image exclude edges.  I need remove outliers and minimize affect to other part of image.